# Does as400 settings at the user profile level or object level override those at the system values?

Tags: ibm-midrange

Does as400 settings at the user profile level or object level override those at the system values? Or is it the opposite instead? Thanks!

For that matter, does group profile settings override user profile settings?

Thanks!

Comment: Which settings? Are you asking about authority?

Comment: Many system values are used as "defaults" for attributes or elements that aren't specified at more detailed levels; those are usually expected to be "overridden", e.g., system value QUSRLIBL. Others are more strict and have no overrides, e.g., system value QALWUSRDMN. It really depends on what specific attributes or elements you need to know about.

Comment: BTW, the same can be said for group profiles and members of groups. Without you saying which attributes are in question, there's no good answer possible. There are too many combinations.